# Output haml content via :ruby filter

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

When I use the `:ruby` filter to do some simple stuff in haml, for example...

```
:ruby
  to = comments > max_comments ? max_comments : comments
  (0...to).each do |i|
    comment = data[i]
    puts li_comment comment[0], comment[1], comment[2]
  end
```

the `puts` statement writes the output to the console. The [docs for :ruby](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter) indicate that it

> Creates an IO object named `haml_io`, anything written to it is output
>   into the Haml document.

How exactly does one *use* the haml_io object to write to the haml document, but not to the console (think I need something other than `puts`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour [changed recently](https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/621) – the old behaviour (before version 4.0) was to write anything written to standard out to the Haml document, but this wasn’t thread safe.

`haml_io` is a [local variable that refers to an IO object that writes to the document](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.3/lib/haml/filters.rb#L293). Your code rewritten to use it would look something like this (assuming `comments`, `max_comments` and `li_comment` are all defined earlier):

```
:ruby
  to = comments > max_comments ? max_comments : comments
  (0...to).each do |i|
    comment = data[i]
    haml_io.puts li_comment comment[0], comment[1], comment[2]
  end
```

`haml_io` is actually a [`StringIO` object](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) so you can use any of its methods, e.g. `haml_io.write`, `haml_io.putc` and it will redirect output to your document.

Answer (score 0):

... Call puts on `haml_io`?

> Anything written to it is output into the Haml document.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit as your renderer rather than plain https://github.com/haml/haml, the syntax for this is different again. It appears you just need to return the value you want from the filter.

None of the standard haml API's appear to work:

```
[46] pry(main)> Hamlit::Template.new() { ":ruby\n  puts 'aaa'" }.render
aaa
=> ""

[47] pry(main)> Hamlit::Template.new() { ":ruby\n  haml_io.puts 'aaa'" }.render
NameError: undefined local variable or method `haml_io' for #<Object:0x00007f9ec2f178a0>
from (__TEMPLATE__):1:in `__tilt_70159905806200'

[49] pry(main)> Hamlit::Template.new() { ":ruby\n  'aaa'" }.render
=> ""
```

But if you return from the `:ruby` filter, you get the output:

```
[50] pry(main)> Hamlit::Template.new() { ":ruby\n  return 'aaa'" }.render
=> "aaa"
```

I opened an issue about this, for reference: https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit/issues/152